# Vertical Scrollview coming for all devices in react native

Tags: iphone, react-native, ipad, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have login view in my react native application.
In small devices like iPhone 5s, The content is out of screen coming. So, I have added scrollview for that to scroll.

But, The scroll is coming in iPhone 6 and all big devices even in iPad too.

My code

> login.js

```
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} contentContainerStyle={LoginStyles.scollView}>
        <View style={LoginStyles.logoContainter}>

//Some more code


        </View>
      </ScrollView>
```

> style.js

```
 scollView: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
```

How to control this in as I mentioned in above big devices?

Comment: Keyboard avoiding view will help sir

Comment: Tried, but not helped, even scroll is not coming.      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} behavior="padding" enabled>

Comment: leave scrollView and go for it sir!

Comment: I removed scrollview and added KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: reffer to this sir this will help 
https://stacktips.com/tutorials/react/creating-login-screen-in-react-native

Comment: KeyboardAvoidingView this class will move/down textinput above keyboard. Anyway thanks for your quick response. But, my issue is, in iPhone 5s my view is hiding.